# AngularJS toggle getting blocked by Math function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have rows where cells are populated with words from an API. I've added a `toggle` feature on the cells to show if a user selected it. I'm using `ng-class={selected:toggle} ng-click="toggle = !toggle"` to toggle a CSS class to show the cell is selected or not.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in game.rows">
  <td id="row-{{$parent.$index+1}}-col-{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="word in row.words" ng-class={selected:toggle} ng-click="toggle = !toggle"><div class="points">{{generateRandomPoints()}}</div>{{word}}</td>
</tr>
```

I added a Math function to the `controller` to randomly assign points to each cell (`<div class="points">{{generateRandomPoints()}}</div>`):

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.generateRandomPoints = function(){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+2);
};
```

This function appears to be blocking my ability to use the `toggle` feature. Another oddity is that each click of a cell re-generates random numbers from the Math function.

Any thoughts why the toggling would be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your generateRandomPoints call is punching through the local scope of your repeated element. Try creating a function like this:

```
$scope.toggle(index) {
    game.rows[index].toggle = !game.rows[index].toggle;
}
```

And call it like `ng-click="toggle($index)"`.

Full documentation for ngRepeat can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).